# _mean() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

Tags: python, data-analysis, physics

I'm trying to find the mean value of some data I took on my physics lab. I'm trying to use .mean() to get the value but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import LT.box as B

file_name ='low_count.py'
f = B.get_file(file_name)

T = B.get_data(f, 'T') #trial numbers
C = B.get_data(f, 'C') #count

C.mean(C, axis=1, dtype=None)
```

This is what I've done so far, I'm trying to do an histogram.

Answer (score 0):

You should do np.mean(, , ) where ,`array` would be 'C' in above case.
[Doing C.mean() might give multiple value arguments)

```
mean_val = np.mean(C, axis=1, dtype=None)
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`LT.box`.`get_data` will get all the values of variable as a `numpy.array()`

#### suppose C is a 1D array

```
import numpy as np
import LT.box as B

C = B.get_data(f, 'C')
C
# array([1, 2, 3])
```

It only has 1 dimension, therefore it's either

**1×n array(axis=0)** or **n×1 array(axis=1)**

next, you wanna get mean value from an array, you can use:

```
C.mean()
```

or

```
np.mean(C)
```

Since it's a 1D array, just leave the `axis` blank(it turns into default, which will automatically know which axis it should be), or choose the right axis yourself.(wrong axis will cause `AxisError`:axis 0|1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0|1)

#### suppose C is a 2D array

```
C = B.get_data(f, 'C')
C
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6]])
```

again, you can use

```
C.mean
```

```
np.mean(C)
```

But the point is, you have to decide which axis' mean you want.

```
C.mean(axis=0)
# array([2.5, 3.5, 4.5])

C.mean(axis=1)
# array([2., 5.])
```

#### Summary

You have to know how the matrix looks like, m × n (m rows by n columns), you have to see it by yourself, just print it out and see how it looks like, then you are good to manipulate them.